# VBA Find What error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Following code gives `Find What:` debug. Trying to look in a range of numerical values (found from a formula in ea cell, same one in ea cell), if value of exactly 0 does not exist then find and select cell with least negative value. Then set that cell to 0 via goal seek.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Cel As Range

    For Each Cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V17:V57")
        If Cel.Value <> 0 Then
    Cel.Find What:=Application.WorksheetFunction.FormulaArray("MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))"), After:=Cells(57, 22), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False

    Cel.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Cel.Offset(0, -4)
        End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

I modified the `Find What` line and there is no more debug error but how can I modify it further to actually `select` the least negative cell it finds?

```
Cel.Find What:=Evaluate("=MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
```

Using `Cel.Select` after the `Find What:` worked

Now my `Find What` is finding the last cell in the range no matter what the value. It is supposed to find the least negative. Any feedback appreciated. This is the code as it stands

```
 For Each Cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V17:V57")
    If Cel.Value <> 0 Then
    Cel.Find What:=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)")
    Cel.Select
    End If
Next Cel
```

Comment: What does the `Application.WorksheetFunction` return? Have you even tried to troubleshoot this?

Comment: There is no `WorksheetFunction` called `FormulaAarray`. See [List of Worksheet Functions Available to Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/list-of-worksheet-functions-available-to-visual-basic). Probably you want to evaluate? `What:=Evaluate("=MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))")`

Comment: Thanks PEH. Your suggestion to use Evaluate looks to have helped.

Comment: I have edited the original question with a revised `Find What` but nothing happens because I need somehow to incorporate an instruction to `select` the cell it finds via the formula

Comment: PEH the formula I'm using is I believe is an array type and would normally need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER if done manually in Excel. At the moment my `Find What:` is finding the greatest negative number. I added `Cel.Select` by the way to my code to `select` the cell found

Comment: Now my `Find What` finds the last cell in the range no matter what the value. It is supposed to find the least negative. I updated original question with latest code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the array worksheet function may be an array of values, which is not a valid parameter for the `.Find` command. Make sure that the parameters that you are feeding to the `.Find` method are valid.

Without seeing your data it is difficult to give more detailed advice.

Comment: Many thanks. I now have the following that doesn't produce an error but how can I modify if to `select` the least negative cell it finds? `Cel.Find What:=Evaluate("MAX(IF(V17:V57<=0,V17:V57),MIN(V17:V57))"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False`

Comment: You are new here, so please read [ask], then edit your question with new or additional info and then post a comment to alert your followers. Also, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: @Nui Furthermore, you should **never** be looking to `Select` in VBA. It's one of the worst programming habits you can develop as a VBA coder, as `Select` is prone to many unforeseen errors. Best avoided altogether

Comment: Rawrplus, I removed the `Cel.Select` and replaced with `.Activate` but this line now gives me a debug error `Cel.Find What:=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)").Activate`

Comment: teylyn the values in my range are numbers derived from a formula…so each of the cells in the given range has a simple mathematical formula in it (the same one in each of the cells in that range)